# Firebase ML Kit giving different Face tracking ID even for same faces in Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I am passing images of the same person first by taking a selfie and the other pic is an existing profile pic of the user which I am converting to File data type because there is no way to directly detect faces from URL in flutter. Even when both faces are the same I am getting different face IDs, as `0` and `1` in print statements. What is the solution to overcome this?

```
Future verifyYourProfile(File image) async {

    final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
      FaceDetectorOptions(
          enableTracking: true, mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate),
    );

    // Assign face ID to selfie from incoming File image called from App.
    final selfieVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(image);
    final selfieFace = await faceDetector.processImage(selfieVisionImage);
    final int selfieId = selfieFace[0].trackingId;
    print(selfieId);

    // Assign face ID to profile Picture.

    // Convert URL Image to File data type
    final response = await get(_imageUrl);
    final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = new File(join(documentDirectory.path, 'verifyImage.png'));
    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);

    print('Detecting second face');
    // Detect the face.
    final faceDetector2 = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
      FaceDetectorOptions(
          enableTracking: true, mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate),
    );
    final profilePicVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(file);
    final profilePicFace =
        await faceDetector2.processImage(profilePicVisionImage);
    final int profilePicId = profilePicFace[0].trackingId;
    print(profilePicId);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question!

The face detection is not designed for face recognition, and it won't tell you whether these two faces belong to the same person or not. The [face tracking ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder#enableTracking()) can be used in streaming mode, where it helps to track the same face in the consecutive frames.